# If a countable union of sets has card $\mathfrak{c}$, prove at least one of them has card $\mathfrak{c}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

If $A=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ and $A$ has cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$, where $\mathfrak{c}$ is the cardinal of the continuum, prove that at least one of the $A_n$ has cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$.

Comment: It might be easier to show that a countable union of countable sets is countable.

Comment: @Dylan Then the rest follows from the truth of the continuum hypothesis?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Ah. Right. I did not think of that.

Comment: @Dylan how to solve this without using the continuum hypothesis cause the question doesn't depend on it

Comment: It's not true. Let $A_1=\{1\}$, $A_2=\{2\}$,..., $A_c=\{c\}$ and $A_n=\emptyset$ for all $n>c$, then $|A|=c$ but not any $A_i$ has card $c$.

Comment: @Surb but by c I mean the cardinal of the continuum

Comment: @hctb: Should do we guess ?

Comment: @Surb sorry I didn't make it clear , I will add that

Comment: @hctb I was able to find this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199274/the-cardinality-of-a-countable-union-of-sets-with-less-than-continuum-cardiality which has an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This follows from König's theorem, which reads

> **Theorem** (König). If for $i \in I$ we have cardinals $\def\a{\mathfrak a}\def\b{\mathfrak b}\a_i < \b_i$, then 
>   $$ \sum_i \a_i < \prod_i \b_i $$

Now suppose for $I = \omega$, we have sets $A_i$ with cardinals $\a_i := |A_i| < \def\c{\mathfrak c}\c$, then 
$$ \left|\bigcup_i A_i\right| \le \sum_i \a_i < \prod_i \c = \c^{\aleph_0} = \c $$
Hence: If $\bigcup_i A_i$ has cardinality $\c$, one of the $A_i$ must also have cardinality $\c$.

Comment: Note that König's theorem is equivalent to the axiom of choice. (The above proposition - that continuum is not a union of countably many sets, all with cardinality strictly lesser than the continuum - is strictly weaker than the axiom of choice.)